# Reading private field in OnCreateDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm writing an application that shows 2 buttons in an alert dialog, one to select objects, other to show the details.

I evaluate if an Map with the new items selected has values but, even clearing the map, the condition returns always false.

Here is the code of the OnCreateDialog() and the AsyncTask were i call the dialog:

```
// Map Containing the objects already selected
Map<String, IdentifyResult> itemsSelected = new HashMap<String, IdentifyResult>();

// Map Containing the new objects selected
Map<String, IdentifyResult> longClickTemp = new HashMap<String, IdentifyResult>();

protected class IdentifyFeatures extends
        AsyncTask<IdentifyParameters, Void, IdentifyResult[]> {

    IdentifyTask identifier;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected IdentifyResult[] doInBackground(IdentifyParameters... params) {
        IdentifyResult[] result = null;

        if (params != null && params.length > 0) {
            IdentifyParameters usedParams = params[0];
            try {
                result = identifier.execute(usedParams);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        identifier = new IdentifyTask(layer2.getUrl());
        progress=ProgressDialog.show(AEP41Activity.this, "Chargement", "Récupération de la sélection");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(IdentifyResult[] result) {
        if (result != null && result.length > 0) {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(AEP41Activity.this, result.length
                    + " objects trouves", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();

            AEP41Activity.this.longClickTemp.clear();
            // Highlight features selected

            for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                // Verify if the object is already selected
                if (itemsSelected.containsKey(result[i].getAttributes()
                        .get("OBJECTID"))) {
                    Log.d("Object Already Exists", "Id: "
                            + result[i].getAttributes().get("OBJECTID"));
                    continue;
                }
                Log.d("Object Found",
                        "Object Type: " + result[i].getLayerName()
                                + " Id: "
                                + result[i].getAttributes().get("OBJECTID"));

                AEP41Activity.this.longClickTemp.put(
                        (String) result[i].getAttributes().get("OBJECTID"),
                        result[i]);
            }
            progress.dismiss();
            AEP41Activity.this.showDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT);
        } else {
            progress.dismiss();
            Toast t = Toast.makeText(AEP41Activity.this,
                    "Aucun objet trouve", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builter = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            AEP41Activity.this);

    switch (id) {
    case CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT:
        builter.setTitle("Selectionner Option");
        if(!longClickTemp.isEmpty()){
            builter.setPositiveButton("Selectionner", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    itemsSelected.putAll(longClickTemp);
                    updateSelectedMenu();
                }
            });
        }
        builter.setNeutralButton("Details", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArrayList("SelectedIds", Utilities.getStringArray(itemsSelected.keySet()));
                b.putSerializable("TabValues", Utilities
                        .getIdentifyResultArray(longClickTemp));
                Intent i = new Intent(AEP41Activity.this,
                        FieldDetails.class);
                i.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        break;
```

Comment: Can you specify which 'condition' are you talking about? Also your code is incomplete, we cannot imagine what `identifier.execute(usedParams);` do.

Comment: identifier.execute(usedParams); is from an API of ArcGIS.
The condition is if(!longClickTemp.isEmpty()), because I clear the map before calling the onCreateDialog.
And after the first execution, this condition is always false

Comment: Did you get any log from `Log.d("Object Found", "Object Type: "...` or a toast message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem of cached dialog.

I didn't know that dialog were cached in android.

To solve the problem, I added:

`removeDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT);`

before `AEP41Activity.this.showDialog(CONTEXT_MENU_SELECT);`